# Selenium select dropdown element using xpath string

Tags: testing, xpath, selenium

I have quite specific problem regarding both selenium and xpath.

I have to make an automated tests based on scenarios using selenium. All pages are automatically generated and using Ids is impossible.

All form elements though are designed in same way.

```
 <table>
 <tr><td> Title </td></tr>
 <tr><td> input/dropdown/etc </td></tr>
 </table>
```

He is the specifics

```
<tr>
<td width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffc7">
<span class="bold">Status wniosku</span>
<span>Test</span>
</td>
<td width="66%" bgcolor="#ffffc7">
<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_2041" class="baseCtrl" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$2041">
<option value="" selected="selected">- wybierz -</option>
<option value="save">tylko zapisz</option>
<option value="pj">zapisz i wyślij do PJ</option>
</select>
<span>
</span>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctl19" class="validation" style="display:none;">Określ status wniosku</span>
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctl20" class="validation" style="display:none;"></span>
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Using http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx I have designed xpath for dropdown elements.

```
//span[text()='LABELNAME']/ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::*/select/option[text()='TEXTVALUE']
```

I would like to use Selenium to click on the element i found.
I've tried Selenium.Click() and variations of Selenium.Select() but with no results.

My question is, is the xpath designed correctly? If so how should i execute it using Selenium? Thx for the help.

Comment: In your example HTML above, what *exact* element are you trying to click? It's hard to tell. Also what browser are you using for this?

Comment: I'm using internet explorer. I'm trying to click one of the dropdown options. I'm not sure if i should be clicking it or selecting it. In my expath im trying to click 'tylko zapisz'. Selenium.Click("//span[text()='Status wniosku']/ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::*/select/option[text()='tylko zapisz'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below xpath for selecting second option

```
"//span[text()='Test']/ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::*/selec‌​t"
```

Ex:

```
Selenium.Select("//span[text()='Test']/ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::*/selec‌​t","label=Save");
```

Comment: It's not working but it gave me the idea of how it should work :)  Selenium.Select("//span[text()='Test']/ancestor::*[1]/following-sibling::*/select","label=Save"); Please edit your post with update so i can thumb up! :)

Comment: It is my pleasure to help you.. :) I've edited my answer bcz, It may useful to some other.